# How to individually resize (rowspan) a time slot in FullCalendar (Scheduler Plugin)?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I think the example images say it all.

How it is by default:
[image]
And how I want it to be:
[image]

Is that possible?

Comment: In a word: No. Not without writing a custom view (or hacking the existing view code). Why do you want to do that? I guess you have different sized default booking slots for each room? You can write business rules to stop users from creating bookings of the wrong length, so maybe that will be sufficient for you.

Comment: I did that, but it's not sufficient. The visual is important for that. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: I would avoid writing a custom view unless you have absolutely no choice at all. Try and get creative about how to solve it. Off the top of my head, another option you could potentially use is to set [background events](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events) to indicate empty slots. They can, of course, be different sizes for different resources.